# Is aggregate initialization of struct safe during refactor?

Tags: c++, struct, refactoring, type-safety, aggregate-initialization

If I have a struct

```
SomeStruct
{
  double y;
  double x;
};
```

and I somewhere initialize it like

```
SomeStruct s{1,2}; //y=1 x=2
```

then it seems that my code can silently break if I reorder my struct to

```
SomeStruct
{
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};
```

since now `SomeStruct s{1,2}` means that x=1, y=2, z=0

Edit:
An argument brought up is that a constructor has the same issue, which is true, but there you can generally see the argument names and orders - even more clearly so if using any modern IDE.

I have not seen anyone ever mention this, but it seems that you can only safely use aggregate initialization like this if you are certain that you will never make changes to the layout of the data. That would be the rare situation, so is there an unspoken rule of "never use aggregate initialization on non homogeneous structs"?

Comment: Constructors have the same problem really. It's much more a question of types than of initialization.

Comment: But if you add a new object to your constructor, the code will not compile if the new one is missing. In the question, the code will compile and no one would recognize that there may be an error.

Comment: @Ventu: OK, that's true, but if you reorder fields of the same type, or reorder constructor parameters, you can still introduce silent changes.

Comment: @Kerrek SB That's right, too.

Answer (score 0):

> Is aggregate initialization of struct safe during refactor?

Depends on how you define "safe" in this context. And what kind of refactoring is done.

> it seems that my code can silently break ... since now `SomeStruct s{1,2}`means that `x=1, y=2, z=0`

Which might be perfectly OK. Why shouldn't z be initialized to 0? You can't tell if its broken until you know what it represents.

This is one of the more benign changes that you can do to a class. A different change such as re-ordering the members would more assuredly require changes in dependent code.

> it seems that you can only safely use aggregate initialization like this if you are certain that you will never make changes to the layout of the data.

Or, if the only changes are expected to be new members that are fine to be value-initialized. (C has support for designated initializers, and those are even resilient to changes to the order of the members. Unfortunately, we don't have them in C++).

Or, if you don't find it a problem to find and update the aggregate initialization. You should know that this possibility exists whenever you make changes to an aggregate.

But indeed, it is true that constructors provide a sort of "implementation firewall" that decouples the user from changes to the members. Some changes like new members may prompt changes to the constructor, but missing constructor arguments do helpfully break the compilation.

> so is there an unspoken rule of "never use aggregate initialization on non homogeneous structs"?

Certainly not without exceptions that you and I have considered. Also, the homo- vs heterogeneity makes no difference.

I would flip the perspective the other way, and say that when designing a *public* API, you should consider whether the layout of a class should be set in stone, or instead make the members private and provide a constructor. For internal API, it doesn't matter so much if you can quickly go through all uses of the class.

---

GCC has a warning option that solves the exact situation that you describe: `-Wmissing-field-initializers` (enabled by `-Wextra`). It will generate a warning if you provide any member initializers, but not all.

Comment: "A different change such as re-ordering the members would more assuredly require changes in dependent code." I am actually reordering x and y, which is the main issue. Perhaps adding in z confused the question. I will edit the question to _only_ mention the reordering.

Comment: @JoeTaicoon don't remove the question about adding a new field. That would make part of my answer obsolete. But feel free to add an edit about reordering. My answer already covers both cases.